# Why was my question immediately closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[Today I questioned](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714140/237923) the claim that "SR is way easier and more beautiful to understand with tensors". I think that knowing about vector spaces, their duals and bilinear forms (i.e. bilinear functions) is enough to formulate the theory and I was genuinely curious to know whether some parts of the theory can really be formulated more conveniently using tensors. The question was immediately closed.

Comment: What is the difference between knowing about tensor products and knowing about vector spaces, their duals, and multilinear forms?

Comment: @WillO Well, you need to know about vector spaces in order to define tensor products, so I would consider tensor products an advanced subject. As far as multilinear forms are concerned, I think I have seen other ways to prove the existence of tensor products (yes, I like to think of tensor products as being defined up to an isomorphism), so I don't think that we need multilinear forms to discuss tensor products.

Comment: I'd have said that a tensor product is, by definition, the universal recipient of a multilinear form (and hence, yes, defined only up to isomorphism).   But I suppose there are other ways to think about it.

Comment: @WillO Yes, you are totally right, I should have thought about that. Of course we need to know about both vector spaces **and** multilinear forms in order to define tensor products. But I'd say that this proves my point that tensor products are an advanced subject :D However, I also realized that if we consider how physicists use the term "tensor", then SR is indeed all about tensors, even we do not invoke tensor products. Do you agree?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about how physicists use the term "tensor" to have an opinion on this!

Comment: @WillO I think you are just humble and actually know more than I do XD Anyways, my opinion is supported by this article. When I studied physics, I thought that understanding tensor products would allow me to understand tensors (and hence theoretical physics in general, as the term appears everywhere). But it didn't. I think you rather need to understand the basics of differential geometry and exterior algebras! In view of how physicists use the term "tensors" I even believe that it only makes sense to talk about tensors given a manifold. Do you have an opinion on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I thought the close reason as opinion-based was reasonably obvious, I've now left a [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714140/sr-is-way-easier-and-more-beautiful-to-understand-with-tensors-is-it#comment1596797_714140) making it explicit:

> Whether one formulation of a theory is "easier" or "more beautiful" than another is a matter of subjective opinion, not an objective question about physics.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I see that my question was badly formulated. I was actually wondering if there are any genuine applications of tensor products to SR. Maybe I'll edit the question.

Comment: I guess that marks a difference between physics and math, where beauty is intrinsic to a result's value.